# Como reverter os envios mais recentes no git?

Tags: git

Eu enviei por acidente os arquivos errados no Git, mas não os coloquei no servidor ainda.

Como posso desfazer esses compromissos do Git?

Comment: Utilize o [Git Reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) `git reset <id-do-último-commit-correto>`. Para capturar o id, basta utilizar `git log`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ git commit -m "Enviado por engano"                        (1)
$ git reset HEAD~                                           (2)
<< edite os arquivos como for necessário >>                 (3)
$ git add ...                                               (4)
$ git commit -c ORIG_HEAD                                   (5)
```

1. Isto é o que você deseja desfazer
2. Isso deixa a sua árvore de trabalho (o estado dos seus arquivos no
   disco) inalterada, mas desfaz o commit e deixa as alterações que
   você comprometeu não registradas (então elas aparecerão como
   "Mudanças não encenadas para confirmar" no status de git e você
   precisará Adicione-os novamente antes de confirmar). Se você quiser
   apenas adicionar mais alterações à confirmação anterior, ou alterar
   a mensagem de confirmação1, você poderia usar o git reset --soft
   HEAD ~ em vez disso, que é como git reset HEAD ~ (onde HEAD ~ é o
   mesmo HEAD ~ 1) mas deixa suas mudanças existentes.
3. Faça correções para os arquivos da árvore de arquivos
4. `git add` qualquer coisa que você deseja incluir em seu novo envio
5. Envie as alterações, reutilizando a mensagem de envio antiga.
   `reset` copiou o cabeçalho antigo para `.git / ORIG_HEAD;` `commit`
   com `-c ORIG_HEAD` irá abrir um editor, que inicialmente contém a
   mensagem de log da confirmação anterior e permite que você a edite.
   Se você não precisa editar a mensagem, você pode usar a opção -C.

---

1 Observação, no entanto, que você não precisa redefinir para um envio anterior se você apenas cometeu um erro na sua mensagem de confirmação. A opção mais fácil é o `git reset` (para subir as mudanças que você fez desde então) e, em seguida, `git commit --amend`, que abrirá seu editor de mensagens de confirmação padrão pré-preenchido com a última mensagem de confirmação.

Tenha cuidado no entanto, se você adicionou novas alterações ao índice, use commit - amend irá adicioná-los ao seu commit anterior.

Comment: **Observação 2:** tanto a pergunta quanto a resposta foram tiradas do [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) oficial, e traduzidas com o objetivo de contribuir com a comunidade do SOPT